# How to rename a method generated by SWIG in c#?

Tags: c#, swig

How can I rename method `Dispose` (generated by SWIG) as `DISPOSE` in the following code?

```
public virtual void Dispose() {
    lock(this)
    {
        if (swigCPtr.Handle != global::System.IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            if (swigCMemOwn)
            {
                swigCMemOwn = false;
                TestPINVOKE.delete_TestCursor(swigCPtr);
            }
            swigCPtr = new global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef(null, global::System.IntPtr.Zero);
        }
        global::System.GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Why? And why can't you simply use the editing/refactoring feature of your editor?

Answer (score 1):

SWIG has a `%rename` directive.  The following is the pattern, but read [the documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIG_rename_ignore) for more details to control renaming:

```
%rename(new_name) old_name;
```

Comment: Thanks for the info @Mark Tolonen. It seems that the `%rename` directive is to rename a function existing on the C wrapper (generated by SWIG). My question is about renaming a method existing on the C# wrapper (generated by SWIG) instead. Do you additional pointers? Thanks!

Comment: @user7698505 Ah, I see.  Dispose is  C# template code generated by SWIG for a C++ destructor.  There is no directive to adjust this that I'm aware of.  You'd have to modify the SWIG template code directly. For example, search the `\Lib\csharp` sources in the SWIG installation for `Dispose`.  Why would you want to change a standard idiom?